# download don't provide client download file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have xlsx file on server and try do send it to client for download or view.
like:

```
var file = name+'.xlsx';
var path = __dirname + '/' + file;
res.dowload(path)
```

i also try path + name, try to set header etc.

```
res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename"+file);
```

but then server response i just have many many coded word but this dont attach me to download file

Comment: i try everything from that post, still response as longlong string

Comment: Try changing `res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename"+file);` into `res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+file);`

Comment: already, still don't attach browser to download xls.